# Why do the TT, TE and EE power spectra in the CMB lead to different values for the Hubble constant?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

[Table 2 of Planck 2018 results](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2020/09/aa33910-18.pdf)

[image]

Why are these three values different? In particular, why is the EE value so much closer to the local universe value, and have so much higher error?

Answer (score -1):

The value of the H0 parameter is calculated along with the four Omega parameters to arrive at the best fit for a Friedmann model for a particular collection of astronomical data. I do not know the specific math used to determine best bit, so I cannot provide any additional details.